# Error inflating class ImageView - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, layout-inflater

I'm designing an app that has a xml file for the list items (list_item.xml), 
and an adapter for the listView (NewsAdapter.java).

My app encounters this error when running:

```
09-22 20:26:29.595 10387-10387/com.example.rh.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rh.newsapp, PID: 10387
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.example.rh.newsapp.NewsAdapter.getView(NewsAdapter.java:38)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1112)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:632)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.example.rh.newsapp.NewsAdapter.getView(NewsAdapter.java:38) 
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346) 
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280) 
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1112) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:632) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013) 
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606) 
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:666)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:160)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
    at android.suppor
```

My list_item file has an ***ImageView***:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baseline="@id/title"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
    tools:ignore="NotSibling" />
```

When I delete ImageView from the list_item.xml, The app runs well!

What should I do?!

NewsAdapter.java:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<News> newsList;

    public NewsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.newsList = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        News current_news = (News) getItem(position);
        View list_view = convertView;
        if(list_view == null) {
            list_view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView title = list_view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView publicationDate = list_view.findViewById(R.id.publicationDate);
        TextView publication = list_view.findViewById(R.id.publication);

        title.setText(current_news.getTitle());
        publicationDate.setText(current_news.getPublication_date());
        publication.setText(current_news.getPublication());

        return list_view;
    }
}
```

list_item.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baseline="@id/title"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
    tools:ignore="NotSibling" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        tools:text="Is technology delivering in schools? Our panel debates" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publicationDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="27 Nov, 2016" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pipe_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/separator_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publication"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="The Guardian" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your complete list_item.xml

Comment: Why don' t you put that `ImageView` inside the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: You can not have multiple root tags in an xml. Put the imageView inside relativeLayout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you see in last lines of error:

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12`

seems you entered something that is not a dimension where you must.
And as documentation of attribute `android:baseline`:

> The offset of the baseline within this view. May be a dimension value,
>   which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as
>   "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent
>   pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches),
>   and mm (millimeters).

But you used a string for value of baseline.

Answer (score 10):

while copying the image files in drawable, you will get option to copy in both drawable and drawable-24. Make sure you copy in both and then try running.

Comment: The error in the heading is related to wrong XML structure, not to drawables.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my application but finally i SOLVED it.
Just put your image file in ic_launcher_background.xml file instead of ic_launcher_foreground.xml file.Hope it helps.